# Who is responsible for deletion of heap allocated object when moving it?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, unique-ptr

What happens when class is created with new, and then move constructor of the class is executed? Is the original creator still responsible for deletion? Example below runs fine (http://ideone.com/rS2LR9), but shouldn't it crash in second scope since owner goes out of scope before vector and hence deletes the object?

I am obviously misunderstanding something here, what happens to the ownership after std::move?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class Owner {
public:
Owner() : data_(new int(1)) {}
int& get() {return *data_;}
private:
std::unique_ptr<int> data_;

Owner(const Owner&) = delete;
void operator=(const Owner&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    {
        Owner owner;
        std::vector<int> test;
        test.emplace_back(std::move(owner.get()));
        std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::vector<int> test;
        {
                Owner owner;
                test.emplace_back(std::move(owner.get()));
        }
        std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
    }

    {
        Owner owner;

        {
            std::vector<int> test;
            test.emplace_back(std::move(owner.get()));
            std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moved objects are in a valid but unspecified state. To this end the destructor of a moved object will be called as soon as the object gets out of scope. Moving of an object doesn't mean that this object is literally moved but rather that the other object steals the memory of the object that is being moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not moving any data here. When you call `Owner::get()`, you're exposing a reference to `int`, and when you call `std::move()` on that reference, you're making a trivial cast. There's nothing for `std::vector::emplace_back()` to "steal" away from `Owner`, because `int` has no move constructor.

I'm guessing that you think that the `std::unique_ptr` inside `Owner` plays into these operations, but it doesn't; you're dereferencing that pointer, but never attempting to move its content. To do so, you'd have to invoke `std::unique_ptr`'s move constructor or assignment operator.